# Set up of virtual environment in anaconda failing

Tags: python, anaconda, virtualenv

I'm trying to create a virtual environment in anaconda python (version 3.6.1 custom 64 bit, conda version 4.5.1)  but it's failing for some reason? The code I used to create the environment is shown below.

```
henry@HB:~$ conda create -n env_zipline python=3.6
```

It then (after a short delay) produced the following errors:

```
Solving environment: failed

# >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ERROR REPORT <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

`$ /home/henry/anaconda3/bin/conda create -n env_zipline python=3.6`

  environment variables:
                 CIO_TEST=<not set>
          COMPIZ_BIN_PATH=/usr/bin/
               CONDA_ROOT=/home/henry/anaconda3
            DEFAULTS_PATH=/usr/share/gconf/ubuntu.default.path
           MANDATORY_PATH=/usr/share/gconf/ubuntu.mandatory.path
                     PATH=/home/henry/Google App Credentials/google-cloud-sdk/bin:/home/henry/.sdk
                          man/candidates/java/current/bin:/home/henry/anaconda3/bin:~/anaconda/bi
                          n:~/anaconda/bin:~/anaconda/bin:/home/henry/bin:/home/henry/.local/bin:/
                          usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
                          :/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
       REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE=<not set>
            SSL_CERT_FILE=<not set>
            XDG_SEAT_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0
         XDG_SESSION_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session0

     active environment : None
       user config file : /home/henry/.condarc
 populated config files : /home/henry/.condarc
          conda version : 4.5.1
    conda-build version : not installed
         python version : 3.6.1.final.0
       base environment : /home/henry/anaconda3  (writable)
           channel URLs : https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forg/linux-64
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forg/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/noarch
          package cache : /home/henry/anaconda3/pkgs
                          /home/henry/.conda/pkgs
       envs directories : /home/henry/anaconda3/envs
                          /home/henry/.conda/envs
               platform : linux-64
             user-agent : conda/4.5.1 requests/2.14.2 CPython/3.6.1 Linux/4.15.0-24-generic ubuntu/16.04 glibc/2.23
                UID:GID : 1000:1000
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False


V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V

CondaHTTPError: HTTP 404 NOT FOUND for url <https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forg/noarch/repodata.json>
Elapsed: 00:00.120726
CF-RAY: 43ede6e4ff8469ef-LHR

The remote server could not find the noarch directory for the
requested channel with url: https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forg

As of conda 4.3, a valid channel must contain a `noarch/repodata.json` and
associated `noarch/repodata.json.bz2` file, even if `noarch/repodata.json` is
empty. please request that the channel administrator create
`noarch/repodata.json` and associated `noarch/repodata.json.bz2` files.
$ mkdir noarch
$ echo '{}' > noarch/repodata.json
$ bzip2 -k noarch/repodata.json

You will need to adjust your conda configuration to proceed.
Use `conda config --show channels` to view your configuration's current state.
Further configuration help can be found at <https://conda.io/docs/config.html>.

A reportable application error has occurred. Conda has prepared the above report.
If submitted, this report will be used by core maintainers to improve
future releases of conda.
Would you like conda to send this report to the core maintainers?
[y/N]:
```

When I do the show channels I get:

```
henry@HB:~$ conda config --show channels
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - conda-forg
  - defaults
```

Can someone please explain

Comment: is `conda-forg` a typo in the `channels` section?

Answer (score 1):

I think this might be a bug. Found open bug report: https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/7568